# Is there a way to force a UIView to release a subview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, retain

Say I pass a UIViewController to a UINavigationController like so:

```
SettingsViewController *settingsRootView = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
    SettingsNavigationController *settingsView = [[SettingsNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsRootView];   
    [settingsRootView release]; 
    [self presentModalViewController:settingsView animated:YES];
    [settingsView release];
```

I release my retain on the original UIViewController, `settingsRootView`, but `settingsView` holds a retain on it. When I dismiss `settingsView`, it should release itself and all of its children, but for some reason it's not. Is there a way to tell my main application view that it's done with `settingsView` to force my main view to release `settingsView` and all of its subviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force your settingsView to release any controllers it is managing, call settingsView.viewControllers = nil.

But this should happen automatically when settingsView is released.  Place a breakpoint in the dealloc method of your settingsView to ensure it is being released.  Make sure dealloc is calling [super dealloc].

Comment: I've verified that dealloc is being called. Perhaps it was my subclass implementation.